# Ontology for Addresses

Tags: rdf, ontology, street-address

I need to create an ontology for scheduling. I use FOAF and Time OWL for storing participants and times, but I also need to store the place, where an appointment take place: the address. Ontologies like GeoNames and WGS84 Geo Positioning don't suite my purposes - I can't store a street there.

I could create that by  my own, but if there is an established  ontology for addresses, then I would use it. I thought about using a vCard Ontology, but it was designed for different purposes. Do you think, it is a good idea? Do you know some other ontology?

Answer (score 7):

I do not think the fact that vcard was meant for a different purpose should be a problem, if the address options in vcard suit your needs.
there are some other vocabularies that cover physical addresses. note however that - internationally - physical addresses are very difficult to standardize (see some information [here](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/3200/ontology-for-all-global-postal-address))

I would propose to look into [LODE](http://linkedevents.org/ontology/)
and into the [future](http://www.w3.org/ns/locn#) w3c location core vocabulary, you will find the current version (proposal) [here](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/asset/core_location/asset_release/core-location-vocabulary-100).

Furthermore, I think asking on http://answers.semanticweb.com could give you more answers.